# Check which process has open SCTP port in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Using Ubuntu Server 16. Something on my machine has an SCTP port open, and I need to find it and kill it (without rebooting).

`lsof` doesn't show SCTP sockets, only TCP and UDP.

I'm looking through all these network utilities, and SCTP support is surprisingly scarce for such an old standard. I got `netstat` to work with SCTP by building the bleeding edge net-tools [from here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/301884785/net-tools_1.60+git20161116.90da8a0.orig.tar.gz). `sudo netstat --sctp -tulpn` shows some open SCTP connections but doesn't say which process has them. It only shows the PIDs for UDP and TCP sockets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort of a hacky roundabout way but it seems to work for me. Hoping someone will find a better way, but my first thoughts (ss/netstat) don't seem to acknowledge SCTP.

First, use `procfs` to find the inode of the sctp connection:

```
$ cat /proc/net/sctp/eps
 ENDPT     SOCK   STY SST HBKT LPORT   UID INODE LADDRS
b6d72780 a8903800 2   10  48   123       0 1895802 0.0.0.0
```

Take that inode (1895802 in my example) and use `lsof` to find who owns it:

```
$ lsof -R | grep 1895802
socat      8697        2045             root    5u     sock    1895802      0t0       SCTP ENDPT: b6d72780 0.0.0.0[123]
```

As you can see, I was using `socat` to make a socket listening on 123/sctp. 8697 is the pid.

Comment: Oh, interesting. The new `netstat` I installed does actually show the PID of my ncat SCTP listener but not the mystery process (or whatever it is). And `procfs` doesn't show anything either. So maybe I somehow have sockets open with no process using them. But that is a separate issue, and this answers my question.